# ng-model not working with ngAutocomplete

Tags: angularjs, mapping-model

I am using angularjs in my web application.I have a text box in which locations are selected with autocomplete.This is done with ngAutocomplete.js(Refering this example http://plnkr.co/edit/il2J8qOI2Dr7Ik1KHRm8?p=preview) .I need to load location from database when page is initially loaded .it is not working now.How can I solve it?

Comment: Do not quite understand. After selecting the location it should appear after the "result"?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/1KVlgCBVUOVRkEVLLqbJ?p=preview Maybe so?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to populate the text boxes with values from a local database instead of them being blank?

Answer (score 2):

Both website and examples are obsolete, and are made after a previous version of the library.

Refer to the [documentation included in the source file](https://github.com/wpalahnuk/ngAutocomplete/blob/master/src/ngAutocomplete.js) instead, you will find out you now need to use `ng-model` attribute.

```
<input type="text" ng-autocomplete ng-model="search.result" details="search.details" options="search.options"/>
```